# Rails cast hash-like objects to hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a single way to cast:

- `Hash`
- `HashWithIndifferentAccess`
- `ActionController:Parameters`

to a `Hash`?

I have a serialized attribute and it looks like all 3 types are in the database table.

Comment: `to_h` would work for these

Comment: `to_h` works for all those?

Comment: yes, see my answer. I'm adding examples right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
hash_like_object.to_h
```

Tested with `Array of arrays`, `Hash`, `HashWithIndifferentAccess` and `ActionController::Parameters` :

```
array      = [[:a,1],[:b,2]]
hash       = {a: 1, b: 2}
hash2      = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(a: 1, b: 2)
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(a: 1, b: 2)

[array, hash, hash2, parameters].each do |hash_like_object|
  h = hash_like_object.to_h
  puts "%s (%s) -> %s (%s)" % [hash_like_object, hash_like_object.class, h, h.class]
end

# [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]] (Array) -> {:a=>1, :b=>2} (Hash)
# {:a=>1, :b=>2} (Hash) -> {:a=>1, :b=>2} (Hash)
# {"a"=>1, "b"=>2} (ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess) -> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2} (Hash)
# {"a"=>1, "b"=>2} (ActionController::Parameters) -> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2} (Hash)
```

Comment: Just using `to_h` (without to_a) works for `HashWithIndifferentAccess` but haven't tested for `ActionController:Parameters`.

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: @archana: Thanks for the comment. I updated the answer.

Comment: `to_h` also turns `nil` into an empty Hash BTW.